# When the navbar closes with a click away, how i can turn off following links or excecute buttons, if the click was on such an item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap 3, Html 5 and CSS 3. The website has a navbar and it closes if the user clicks away of the navbar. But if the user clicks then on an item like a link it follows the link. How i can block those elements when i click away from the navbar for closing the drop down of the navbar? I want to remove those side-effects.

```
$('body').click(function (event) {
    // If user does not click on navigation and navigation drop down is visible.
    if (!($(event.target).is('#navigation *')) && $(".navbar-collapse").is(":visible") && $(".navbar-toggle").is(":visible")) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');
    }
});
```

What do I have to add that the area which is shown on screen next to the navigation do not excecute links etc. when the user clicks them for closing menue..

Thank you already!

Comment: Please post example code. Show us what you've done and what doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on the navigation bar, you need to disable the click event.You can do it with javascript.

```js
jQuery( '.dropdown-menu > li' ).click( function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: This would be for not following navbar-element-links or am I wrong? I wanna block the part next to the navbar?